# SQL DISTINCT RETRIEVING ALL OTHER COLUMNS OF THE SAME RECORD

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I'm using PostgreSQL

I have a table with information about prospect clients, that looks like this:

```
ID | Phone        | link
1  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_1
2  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_2
3  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_3 
4  | 3153333651   | https://link_for_id_4
5  | 3153333651   | https://link_for_id_5
```

The aim is to use this data for reporting to the sales team. But the requirement is that there will not be repeated phone numbers. In this case, my desired output would be:

```
ID | Phone        | link
1  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_1
5  | 3153333651   | https://link_for_id_5
```

For that purpose i'm using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Phone,
                max(ID), -- Here using aggregated functions to allow ID and link to visualize
                max(link) 
FROM MyTable
```

But this approach sometimes give me links that not correspond to my ID's:

```
ID | Phone        | link
1  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_3
5  | 3153333651   | https://link_for_id_4
```

Is there a way to retrieve unique Phones with the condition that the ID and Link correspond to the same record?

Comment: How do you know what is the correct link?

Comment: I mean what is the correct link for 3105637247 and why ?

Comment: Hi @LeandroBardelli, as you can see the last character of the link is the same as the id. This is the way I know what is the correct result.

Comment: I know, but why do you "remove" 2 and 3? Easily you could say that the correct link is 3.

Comment: For eg: Why `1  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_1` and not `3  | 3105637247   | https://link_for_id_3`

Comment: @LeandroBardelli, this is just a subset of the table, each record is a different product that is published by the same number, for that reason has different links. It doesn't matter what to choose, if ID 1 or ID 3, but it matters that the link and ID correspond to the same record

Comment: About `DISTINCT ON`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Postgresql's `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (Phone) t.*
from Mytable t
order by Phone
```

Or do `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from Mytable t
where not exists (select 1 from Mytable t2
                  where t2.Phone = t1.Phone
                    and t2.id < t1.id)
```